# Excel- function to sum non-empty columns then find string if majority

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I apologize for the confusing title, I was not sure how to phrase this question.

I have a (dynamic and constantly updating) database of stocks in column C. In columns D through L, there are names of people who have invested in the stock.

In each group of 4 stocks (so stock 1 through stock 4) each person can choose to invest in ONLY 2 stocks. However, each person does not always participate. For example, Person 10 below did not participate in picking stocks until the second round. And Person 9 only participated in picking stocks the first round (stocks 1-4). The round number is reflected in column A and the total number of votes for each stock is reflected in column B.

I want to write a function that can tell me how often each person picked a stock that was in the majority

```
1 2 Stock 1 Person 1    Person 2                            
1 7 Stock 2 Person 3    Person 4    Person 5    Person 6    Person 7    Person 8    Person 9        
1 8 Stock 3 Person 2    Person 3    Person 4    Person 5    Person 6    Person 1    Person 7    Person 8    
1 1 Stock 4 Person 9                                
2 6 Stock 5 Person 6    Person 4    Person 3    Person 7    Person 1    Person 10           
2 7 Stock 6 Person 6    Person 8    Person 4    Person 3    Person 1    Person 10   Person 2        
2 1 Stock 7 Person 7                                
2 2 Stock 8 Person 2    Person 8
```

I want to find the percent of times each person was in the majority. For example, Person 10 was in the majority for both of the stocks that he/she picked. Therefore, Person 10 would be 100% (even though Person 10 did NOT vote in the first 4 stocks it should not be counted against his/her percentage).

Person 1, however, participated in picking stocks 1-8 and was in the majority 3/4 times. Her percentage would be 75%.

I honestly don't even know where to begin. The fact that I do not want the stocks a person did not pick between to count against them is making me confused. I hope my explanation makes sense, if anyone has suggestions about the first step to take, I would appreciate it!

Comment: What defines the order of the stocks?  since each is in a group of 4... or what defines the group?  order in a table isn't guaranteed and I see nothing in the exmaple which defines the order, other than the order in the excel document itself (row number) ...

Comment: You stated person 8 was 3/4 but I only see the person 8 having 3 selections.  So why wouldn't they have a 2/3 ratio?  I started with adding a column to A to define the groups using `=CEILING(ROW()/4,1)`  I considered unpivoting the name data so that you could pivot by name and out of stock.. and group.

Comment: If you scroll you will see Person 8's 4th selection (for some reason it got cut off- but it is there)

Comment: And the stocks are in groups of 4. Adding a column A to define the groups is a good idea, however, and I will update the sheet to reflect this